# How to download file from remote server to windows without sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ftp, sudo

I have a VM running Ubuntu 14.04. I seem to have broken sudo on my account:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

I do not have root access. I am looking to download a folder off the VM to my local computer before reinstalling it. The folder in question has 777 permission. I cannot connect via ssh or ftp/sftp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Live CD to boot the VM. After boot into the Live CD, mount the virtual disk and copy whatever folder you want. You can also try to fix the problem given that you already have the error message.